# Add a label showing server time to SE pages

Tags: discussion, feature-request

well, I'm pretty sure it won't be more than two or three lines of code, But I would appreciate a simple server time somewhere in page (maybe in it's footer). The things is one can't really tell when a day ends and when a new one begins! I'm not sure how many people will need this but still it would be nice to know when the day number is going to be changed!

Comment: Why is it important to know?

Comment: It helps if you know where the day rolls over. since there are many things that are bundled with day cycle in this site. for example we have daily reputation (and also it's cap), and the visiting streak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your profile, if you hold your mouse over `seen: 1 second ago`, it will display a tooltip with the near current [UTC time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). I will assume that days roll-over at midnight [Zulu Time](https://www.google.ca/search?q=zulu+time).

Comment: that does help actually :D